# how we can do like on click combobox scroll keyboard collapse and onclick keyboard raise

Tags: android, kendo-ui, telerik

We want to close / Collapse keyboard on scrolling of combo box and then if click on text combobox then raise the keyboard of android 
Currently keyboard is set upper to the combobox list so we need to hide that

Comment: specify developing environment and language

Comment: Developing in cordova android and  ios app